# Android: VPN service setBlocking Mode

Tags: android, vpn

I'm quite new to android programming and I've been trying to build a custom VPN and I noticed .setBlocking  method in the builder class which returns a parcel file descriptor in blocking mode.
After a lot of searching I didn't find any documentation of what this means.
Can anyone point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

five years later it can be found in documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#setBlocking(boolean)

If you want set blocking mode using API older than 21, you can create JNI module with fcntl syscall.